# seting up Spring for MVC application with JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, glassfish

i am developing one web application using Spring and that application has connectivity with database so for database connection iam using JPA , now the problem is that i donot know whether i add external jpa jar for databse connection or spring data JPA  is enough i donot need to add external jars? and when when i add spring data jpa jars for accessing its crud reporsitory interfaces then i get exception on my application server that failed to connect with localhost 1527 port ...

Answer (score 1):

Install [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and use the maven `pom.xml` from the spring examples that match your application best (for example http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).

Maven will all the dependencies/jars configured in the pom es well as the transitive required dependencies (the one that are required bz the dependencies/jars taken form the pom, and so on)